# Migrate mySQL to Firebase

Tags: mysql, firebase, database-migration

So i have an application which currently stores data on an apache server and mysql. I want to migrate to firebase but i have the following problem:

My data is a Business table where each user has stored their data. This includes their email and all the data of their business (address, city, business name, etc.) I have exported the data in json and import it to firebase, but now i want the users to create a new profile (in firebase) and then "claim" their data.

This should be done in order to create a relationship between the user and the business.

Any ideas on how to do that?

**EDITED:**

So the problem was that i had the business and my user in one object or table like this:

```
{
  "user_type": "Hotel",
  "state": "Lakonia",
  "postcode": "23100",
  "city": "Mystras",
  "country": "Greece",
  "id": 1,
  "num_of_rooms": "5",
  "email": "info@email.com",
  "address": "Something",
  "time_of_register": "",
  "name": "My hotel",
  "latlng": ""
}
```

In order to migrate it to `Firebase`, I created a check, so when a user logs in, the system runs a query and if the users registration email is the same with one of the businesses, i move it to a new firebase data set, registered with the users unique key. Thus no i have two sets, one for my users and one for the business info.

Answer (score 5):

Should be fairly straight forward

```
Users
  User_id_0
     Name: frank
     Business_ref: Business_id_0
  User_Id_1
     Name: buzz
     Business_ref: Business_id_1

Businesses
  Business_id_0
     Business_name: Code'r' us
     Owner: User_id_0
  Business_id_1
     Business_name: Burger Boooyaa
     Owner: User_id_1
```

Comment: I am looking for an option from firebase that can actually do that automatically  as i have more than 1000 users. 

Finally i decided to get the email from the current data set, compare it to the users and add the business to a new data set with the users key included. 

Thank you.