# Can you transfer data from godaddy SQL database to firebase real-time database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My company is trying to take historic data from our godaddy SQL database and put it into the JSON real-time database on Firebase. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic migration tool for moving data from a SQL database to the Firebase Realtime database. Part of the reason of this is that the data models are very different. SQL databases have a relational data model, while Firebase uses NoSQL data models. In the case of the Firebase Realtime Database the data model is a JSON tree, like a traditional hierarchical database.

This topic is really incredibly broad and hard to answer here in a single answer on Stack Overflow. For a good introduction to the topic, I recommend:

- reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)

And some previous questions on the topic:

- [Migrating data into Firebase from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916172/migrating-data-into-firebase-from-mysql)
- [Migrate mySQL to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425743/migrate-mysql-to-firebase)
- [How do i sql export table structure and data to firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600447/how-do-i-sql-export-table-structure-and-data-to-firebase)